# Laravel orderBy: calling it to a non-object

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to order a list of content from my database. I want it to order by the newest content goes at the top of the page and the oldest at the bottom. I have a datetime the holds the created_at time. The problem I am having is where to put the orderBy('created_at') in my template. It keeps saying I am calling it to a non-object.

Here is my code:

```
@if($posts->count())
    @foreach($posts as $post)
        <article>
            <h2><a href="{{ URL::action('post-show', $post->slug) }}">{{ $post->title }}</a></h2>
            {{ Markdown::parse(Str::limit($post->body->orderBy('created_at')->get(), 300)) }}
            <p>Published {{ $post->created_at->diffForHumans() }}</p>
            <a href="{{ URL::action('post-show', $post->slug) }}">Read more &rarr;</a>
        </article>
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Looks like a lot but pay most of your attention to the {{ Markdown area. How would I include the orderBy and get it to put the newest entries in first on the page.

Here is my controller:

```
<?php

class PostController extends BaseController {
public function getShow($slug) {
    $post = Post::where('slug', '=', $slug)->firstOrFail();

    return View::make('posts.show')->with('post', $post);
}
```

}

Comment: I did add the controller just now

Comment: _in the controller:_ `$post = Post::where('slug', '=', $slug)->orderBy('created_at')->firstOrFail();` what i don't understand is, what's up with multiple contents with same slug? it will become _ambiguous_.

Comment: That didn't work it still displays by id

Comment: `@if($posts->count())` from where this `$posts` coming from?

Comment: How do I make the newest post show first. The oldest shows first and newest last?

Answer (score 0):

Itachi is correct just missed the `'DESC'`:

```
   $post = Post::where('slug', '=', $slug)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->firstOrFail();
```

Take note that `firstOrFail` will only return one result set though.